# Checkbox WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi all i have problem in this code, please help me..

I have view

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">
            <Label Content="Audit Type" MinWidth="100"/>
            <Label Content=":"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="3" SelectionMode="Extended" MinWidth="180">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Name="check" Content="{Binding Value}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

and for View model

```
private List<AuditTypeExport> _items;
private List<string> _value;
private bool _isChecked;

public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public List<AuditTypeExport> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    public List<string> Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set 
        { 
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
```

And ViewModel Constractor

```
_items = _model.GetAuditType();
_value = _model.GetAuditType().Select(item => item.Name).ToList();
```

For your information

```
public class AuditTypeExport
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;

    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

The result : checkbox appeares, but the content doesn't and I don't have a clue why.

Question Number 2 : I want to get the value back, how can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need the _value field/Value property. You should bind to the name property of the AuditExporType. I don't see how the two are kept in synch, or how the ListBox would know to reconcile the Items collection and the Value collection.

Comment: you should consider changing your labels to textblocks--they are more lightweight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear how you are using your ViewModel.  Is that bound to the form?  Or each item in the ListBox?

It looks like your ListBox is bound to the Items collection of your VM, so the ItemTemplate will be used with a AuditTypeExport as the data context.  You are binding to "Value" and "IsChecked" properties which do not exist on the AuditTypeExport class.

Comment: i am newbie in MVVM, so i confused. Just took code from somebody and try it. From mycode, it suppose ItemTemplate get List<AuditTypeExport>, Value get from ViewModel --> AuditTypeExport.Name , and IsChecked get from user use it. is that right ?

Comment: This is not something that can be answered simply.  You need to learn MVVM properly.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is bind a property of type `List<String> Value` to `CheckBox`'s `Content` property which is of type `Object`.

To simplify, you are assigning a collection of strings to a string. Which is not a good thing. And that is why it does not work.

Try using `ItemsControl` to show `Value` property or use an `IValueConverter` to convert `List<String>` to comma separated string.